# Nest.js monorepo make a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nestjs, monorepo

I am trying to make a dockerfile to make an image for each microservice but it always fails and don't even really know how to do it in my case.

Here is my folder structure:

I am not even sure that it is what I am supposed to do but now I've tried the following things:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY libs ./libs
COPY apps/ms-content ./ms-content
COPY apps/$MS_NAME ./apps/$MS_NAME

RUN npm ci

# Stage 2: Production
FROM node:18-alpine

ARG MS_NAME

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules

RUN npm run build

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/apps/api-gateway ./apps/dist/$MS_NAME

CMD node --max-old-space-size=256 $(find apps/dist/$MS_NAME -name "main.js")
```

And I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-08-28T11_36_02_590Z-debug-0.log
```

I was expecting to be able to build a **dockerfile** for each microservice and run them separately

**[EDIT]:**

I tried something else and it works but only for api-gateway

```
# Stage 1: Builder
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./

#COPY ./apps/api-gateway ./apps/api-gateway

RUN npm i

RUN npm run build

CMD node --max-old-space-size=256 ./dist/apps/api-gateway/main.js
```

If i put for exemple `ms-content` instead of `api-gateway`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/apps/ms-content/main.js'
2023-08-28T14:36:30.556942436Z     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
2023-08-28T14:36:30.557107613Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
2023-08-28T14:36:30.557332231Z     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
2023-08-28T14:36:30.557342707Z     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2023-08-28T14:36:30.557346727Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-08-28T14:36:30.557710692Z   requireStack: []
2023-08-28T14:36:30.557717216Z }
```

When I list the `/dist/apps` folder I get only `api-gateway` inside but not other apps.

What i've found is that only `api-gateway` is working was because of my ``nest-cli.json` config:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/api-gateway/src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "webpack": true,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/api-gateway/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
```

If I do replace `api-gateway` by for i.e. `ms-content`, only this app is built...

Comment: In your second stage, "Production", where do you copy the package.json?